# How do massive objects bend spacetime if space is just an empty being?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

According to general relativity, space and time are interwoven to form the fabric and mesh of spacetime. But if space is an empty void thing and time is also not a physical substance or concept, then how do objects with mass bend spacetime around it?

Comment: "Space is not a physical substance or concept" not sure where you got this idea.

Comment: Think that we give sense to spacetime when having a body trajectory. You do not need space as a "solid" or a physical frame. Actually  what is bent is the behaviour of something we can sense, matter or light.

Answer (score 2):

Spacetime is not substance. It is a manifold on which matter plays with each other. Probably the word bend is a bit misleading. In case of vacuum, spacetime has the usual flat metric, which we are familiar with, just Lorentz metric with sign (-1,1,1,1).
However, there is no reason to believe that the spacetime will behave exactly the same when there is matter. Take it this way, if there is matter, then the points in spacetime is no longer equivalent to each other, and there is no reason to believe that they will behave the same mathematically. In that case, the metric is determined by the famous Einstein equation.

Answer (score 1):

There are the astrophysical observations from ancient times  to now. With [Newtonian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion) up to two centuries ago, most observation, data in numbers, could be fitted/modeled , and new predicted, where space was just the coordinate system of the planets , stars, galaxies and clusters of galaxies. With the Michelson Morley experiment the [luminiferous aether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminiferous_aether) was disproved , so there was no medium on which light waves could travel, in this coordinate syste,

Then astrophysical  observational measurements became more and more accurate, and discrepancies were discovered in  predictions that could not be modeled using   the Newtonian theory,  a new mathematical theory was needed. This came with the theory of [General Relativity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity)

In this theory

> General relativity generalizes special relativity and refines Newton's law of universal gravitation, providing a unified description of gravity as a geometric property of space and time or four-dimensional spacetime. In particular, the curvature of spacetime is directly related to the energy and momentum of whatever matter and radiation are present. The relation is specified by the Einstein field equations, a system of partial differential equations.

This theory instead of using space and time  variables just as only convenient coordinates for measuring astrophysical observations, connects space and time with the gravitational masses in a differential equation , that has been proven to describe the observations Newtonian gravity could not, while at the limit of low masses and energies is the same as the Newtonian theory.

Space and time in this theory are coordinates given in a [four vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) of special relativity. If there are no masses present the coordinates are flat . If there are masses each coordinate axis cannot be described by a straight line, but i curves according to the masses and radiation one is modeling, because the theory connects the space four vector with the energy and momentum four vector, through the equations,

[image: einstein eq]

You should go to link given if you are really interested.

You ask:

> how do objects with mass bend spacetime around it

Anyway, this is how the theory of General Relativity predicts that if there is mass or radiation, spacetime  cannot be described by linear axes for coordinates, but needs curved ones.